# How can I use tag slugs in URLs?

Tags: entries, relations, tags

**This question is a summary of my working with tags yesterday, I'm posting my findings to SE so other people can benefit.**

---

For the purposes of this question, I'm going to be using a tag with the title 'Two Words'.

I'm trying to add a tags listing and filtering system to a blog. As tags don't have a 'slug' property, I've been having issues using them in URLs. If I use the following links:

```
{% for tag in tags %}
    <a href="/news/tags/{{ tag.title }}">{{ tag.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Then you get unfriendly urls such as `http://craft.dev/news/tags/Two%20Words`. If I use :

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.search(craft.request.getSegment(3)) %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo(tag) %}
```

Then I get a list of articles that may contain the term "two words", but aren't actually tagged with `Two Words`.

I want to list articles related to the tag in the URL, so how can I pull the specific tag from the url, making sure it stays 'url-friendly'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to this is to use the `|kebab` filter and the `relatedTo` params.

**Listing:**

```
{% for tag in relatedTags %}
    <li><a href="/news/tags/{{ tag.title|kebab }}">{{ tag.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

**Fetch related articles**

```
{% set tag = craft.tags.search(craft.request.getSegment(4)) %}

{% for entry in craft.entries.relatedTo({ targetElement: tag[0], field: tagField }) %}
```

The `tag[0]` is necessary, as `{{ craft.tags.search() }}` will return an array (even if there's only one tag returned).

This finds entries that are specifically related to `Two Words` (a tag object, pulled from the URL), and searches in the `tagField` specified.

The alternative to the above is to use `{{ tag.id }}` and `{{ craft.tags.id() }}`, but that isn't URL/SEO friendly.

Answer (score 1):

It's <s>not documented</s>, but it looks like there's both, a `slug` property for tags and also a `slug` parameter for the `craft.tags` criteria model.

```
{% set tagSlugs = 'one,two,three'|split(',') %}

{% set tags = craft.tags.slug(tagSlugs) %}

{% for tag in tags %}
    {{ tag.slug }}
{% endfor %}
```

**Update:**
Both the `slug` property and the param are now mentioned in the Craft docs.